# Python: Plugging in range of values for likelihood function always returns same value

Tags: python, loops, numpy, data-fitting

I am writing a program to calculate a likelihood function. The parameter I am trying to fit is I. This is my function:

```
#loglikelihood
def like_xe(I):
    model=(0.1535*(Z/A)*((charge*c/v_array)**2))*(np.log((2*m_e*(gamma_array**2)*(v_array**2)*(w_array)/((I*1.6E-6)**2)))-(2*(v_array/c_speed)**2))
return np.sum(((-0.5*np.log(2*np.pi*xe_un))-((xe_sp-(model))/(2*xe_un**2))))
```

The "arrays" are all data arrays, all of length 50. Then, I want to calculate the likelihood function for 1000 values of I between 0.0001 and 0.001, and from this data extract the maximum value of the likelihood function.

```
I_list=np.arange(1E-4,0.001,1000)
like_val=[0 for like in range(len(I_list))]
for like in range(len(I_list)):
    like_val[like]=like_xe(I_list[like])
```

This only returns [-169.58003268336941]. Obviously, this is incorrect. What is the matter with how I am approaching this problem? Is it possibly because it only reads the return statement once?

EDIT: Changed the np.arange to np.linspace. This creates an array of the correct size, however, it is entirely full of the value -169.58003268336941.

Comment: When posting example code it might be easier to put things into variables instead of a single giant line.

Answer (score 1):

np.arange takes start, stop and step.  A step of 1000 between 1e-4 and 0.0001 means 1 value.

```
>> np.arange(1E-4,0.001,1000)
array([ 0.0001])
```

replace this with np.linspace and you should get a better iteration:

```
>> np.linspace(1E-4,0.001,10)
array([ 0.0001,  0.0002,  0.0003,  0.0004,  0.0005,  0.0006,  0.0007,
    0.0008,  0.0009,  0.001 ])
```

(set to 10 rather than 1000 for brevity)

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Comment: This indeed returns a list of the correct size! However, each value in this list is the exact same: -169.58003268336941, just now 1000 times.

Comment: the source of this error is within your like_xe function which I am not able to debug due to the undefined constants.